# Return to LispWorks listener from terminal on Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, common-lisp, lispworks

I am using the LispWorks program to write and test Lisp code. When I mistakenly create an infinite loop, the Terminal on my Mac pops up. Is there a way to return to the LispWorks program from the Terminal, without having to quit both the Terminal and LispWorks?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide the code you have written so that someone can answer in a way that will help others in the future.